# Repeat Brackets by Multipliers in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am working on a textile designing program. need to convert  design report parentheses to simple format as below. (unlimited inner parentheses also possible)

> 2(1A 2B) 2(2(1C 2D) (1A 2B)) 4E 5F => (1A 2B)(1A 2B) (1C 2D)(1C 2D)(1A 2B)(1C 2D)(1C 2D)(1A 2B) 4E 5F

How to realize it?

Comment: "In a language or layer that is not t-sql" is probably the best answer.

Comment: You are definitely right Alex. But sometimes you need to do something which you don't want to do ..

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: The SQL version is 11.0.2

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL CLR functions? And are you able/have rights to create such objects, or you need pure T-SQL solution?

Comment: Yes I have full rights on database. but not so familiar with CLR functions. But such solutions also possible.